# how to use insert into in DolphinDB

Tags: dolphindb

here is my code below:

```
insert t1(tradingDay) into values (timestamp(datetimeParse(`20180307,"yyyyMMdd")))
```

and found that it is not the same as the relational database. like ORACLE inserts a whole column, while dolphinDB inserts only one data.

Then how do i insert a certain column in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 0):

The following code will insert 2 columns and 2 rows:

```py
insert into t(ticker, volume) values(`UBER`LYFT, 0 0);
```